# Increase screen resolution in VirtualBox guest without VirtualBox guest additions?

Tags: linux, virtualbox, virtual-machine, fedora, resolution

Without VirtualBox guest additions installed, the only screen resolution is 640x480:

```
$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 640 x 480, maximum 640 x 480
default connected primary 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   640x480       73.00*
```

How can the resolution be set to 1280x1024, for example?
No VirtualBox guest additions should be necessary.

The guest is a Fedora system.

I've tried adding an [Xorg config file as described by this Whonix article](https://www.whonix.org/wiki/Higher_Screen_Resolution), which did exactly nothing.

Using cvt to get a new modeline for xrandr does not seem to work either:

```
$ cvt 1280 1024
# 1280x1024 59.89 Hz (CVT 1.31M4) hsync: 63.67 kHz; pclk: 109.00 MHz
Modeline "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
$ xrandr --newmode "1280x1024_60.00"  109.00  1280 1368 1496 1712  1024 1027 1034 1063 -hsync +vsync
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
$ xrandr
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
Screen 0: minimum 640 x 480, current 640 x 480, maximum 640 x 480
default connected primary 640x480+0+0 0mm x 0mm
   640x480       73.00* 
  1280x1024_60.00 (0x1bd) 109.000MHz
        h: width  1280 start 1368 end 1496 total 1712 skew    0 clock  63.67KHz
        v: height 1024 start 1027 end 1034 total 1063           clock  59.89Hz
$ xrandr --addmode default 1280x1024_60.00
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
$ xrandr --output default --mode 1280x1024_60.00
xrandr: Failed to get size of gamma for output default
xrandr: Configure crtc 0 failed
```

Comment: I am not in front of a  VB installation but as far as I recall, you need to install the DKMS module from the Guest Additions if you want higher screen resolution.

Comment: I wrote that I don't want guest additions.

Comment: Not possible to do without guest additions.

Answer (score 2):

1) Stop XOrg

```
 stop REPLACEWITHNAMEOFXORGSERVICE
```

2) Open console

```
CTRL-ALT-F1
```

3) Create default xorg.conf, it not exists

```
X -configure
```

4) Move xorg.conf.new so system uses config file

```
mv xorg.conf.new /etc/X11/xorg.conf
```

5) Reboot

```
reboot
```

6) Modify xorg.conf, add

```
Section "Monitor"
...
 HorizSync 1.0 - 1000.0
 VertRefresh 1.0 - 1000.0
 Option "MinClock" "1.0"
 Option "MaxClock" "10000.0"
 Option "Primary" "True"
 Option "PreferredMode" "1920x1080"
...
EndSection
```

7) Reboot

```
reboot
```

8) System Settings > Display > "Select Any -4:3- Resolution"

9) Enable widescreen

```
Host:VBoxManage setextradata "YOURGUEST" "CustomVideoMode1" "1920x1080x32"
```